# Is there a way to keep youtube api events functioning after using detach in jquery?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

This is the basics as I am sure you guys know how Youtube API's works far more than I.

But basically:

```
    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        playerVars: {
          'playsinline': 1
        },
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        alert("vid ended");
      }
    }
    $("#movePlayer").on("click", function() {

      var d_vid = $("#player").detach();
      $(this).append(d_vid);
    });
```

The video is appended and that works just fine. But when the video ends - none of the api events work. Is there something I am missing. I could have sworn that I got this to work a while back but I could be wrong.

If anyone has any suggestions, I am all ears!

Comment: I would guess you need to use a delegated event handler, but it depends on how the events are being raised/caught, and where that logic is contained

Comment: RORY HERE YOU GO: https://jsfiddle.net/9vnhcjzr/

Note: Let the video player finish and you will and alert popup. But after you detach the video player and append it elsewhere - the onstatechange and alertbox does not execute.